# Draw lines with manim library?

Tags: python, manim

I started learning manim and I hope you could help me understand how this code works

```
class Line_1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        path = Line(LEFT*5,RIGHT*5,stroke_opatity=0.5)
        path.points[1:3] += UP*2
        self.add(path)
```

When I run the code I get this:
[image]

However I do not know how to interpret this "path.points[1:3] += UP*2"
What does it mean .points[1:3]?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All VMobjects (Lines, Circles, etc) are Bezier curves, and all Bezier curves have control points, those control points are in the `.points` attribute, the lines have 4 control points, and what that code does is to move the intermediate control points (I do not move the ends).